# Excel VBA Early/Late Bind Shockwave Object

Tags: excel, vba, flash

I created a workbook using Excel 2013 and inserted a Shockwave Flash player to play YouTube Videos and all worked fine until that workbook traveled to several other computers. One using Excel 2013 and one using Excel 2016. On the Excel 2013 computer I had installed adobe flash player and shockwave but when I opened the workbook it error out and said "Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine. On the Excel 2016 computer it worked fine and did not have Flash or Shockwave installed. I've read about early and late binding and that that method would have the object created travel with the workbook irregardless of the Excel version. Using code can someone show how this can be handled. I've checked searching for additional controls on 2013 and 2016 but one object points to a .dll file and one points to a .ocx?

Comment: Let me clarify. I created a user form with a shockwave flash object. The Excel I used allowed me to do this because I had the reference to shockwave library. I removed the reference and it works fine on the computer that created the workbook on. When I pass this workbook to Excel users they get the message "cannot load an object because it is not available on this machine." What I would prefer to do is, is to test first to see if that form could load without error or, cannot load with error, and if it cannot load display a message before the form opens and exit the sub.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but it sounds like it **links** the SWF file instead of embedding it into the workbook. So, the SWF file is only on your dev computer and everywhere else your workbook has a link to non-existing file.

Comment: How would to embed it versus link it?

Comment: No idea. Maybe you should distribute SWF file along with workbook file, and everything will be fine? Or not. Recently Excel didn't open 2 different files from 2 different places for me just because file names were the same. We could expect just any unexpectable evil move from these inhumanoid alien guys who programmed it.